# IOS plugins listed but xcode says not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, ionic-plugins

I am getting this error with all of my plugins. It shows that all of my plugins are not installed however they are.

> WARN: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.

I saw a similar article that suggested to make sure that code isn’t executed outside of platform.ready but that does not seem to be my issue

My package.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "ppc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/device-orientation": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "convert-units": "^2.3.4",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.8.15",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^1.0.6",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "haversine": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.3.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rm": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.6",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please assist. This is only happening on IOS. Android is fine. tested on simulator and device.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove ios platform and add it again will works .
Try this commands:-

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: done this many times already, also deleted npm and reinstalled

Comment: no luck with this, also just removed every plugin and reinstalled

Comment: turned out not to be an issue, the plugins were installed but xcode for some silly reason said they were not. the components in my app are working fine, the diagnostics plugin just needed to be called on app startup or before entering a page that it was going to be used on.